# Collect CPU info of the server using SIGAR

Tags: cpu-usage, sigar

We need to monitor couple of Server's CPU for that i believe SIGAR is the best choice. We want to install the SIGAR libraries as rpm(redhat) and need a documentation to show us how to start the SIGAR to collect the data from server. Once the data is collect we can take care of pushing the data to webserver which will parse the data and plots a graph.

I am very new to SIGAR and ignorant of what it is capable of so i am posting my question here.

Note: We don't want to install any additional software on the Server such as JVM etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... if SIGAR depends on Java to run it, or needs an application to call its methods, then it won't be able to just be included.

However, if it's able to be configured using the instructions / details they provide then sure.  I think you need to rephrase your question.

Comment: @TehHippo i have rephrased my question.

Comment: Removed some unneeded tags.  Hope you get an answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

If Server's CPU Info is the only thing you are after, just create SSH tunnels to your target server(s) and run SAR command periodically and parse the results for your graphs.